# How do you allow only one instance of an inherited window to be open?

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, singleton

I've been working with WPF for a little while now and I've had trouble forcing only one instance of a window to open from my MainWindow. I've been trying to find out if the solution I chose is the best one but there does not seem to be a lot in the way of this subject. Makes me wonder if I am going about it entirely the wrong way.

The original problem I was trying to solve was only allow one instance of a window to open, which I accomplished using a singleton model. It ended up working just fine, but I have two windows I want to open that I'd like this functionality on. I figured it would be nice to make a "BaseWindow" to inherit from, so I'd only need to implement this once. That's where I got stuck.

I've created a very simple project where I am trying to implement this idea, but instead I am getting hit with a protectional level error on the AboutWindow's public contructor, because the WindowBase contructor is private. Changing it to public allows the program to compile, but it seems to "skip" the AboutWindow contructor which has "InitializeComponent".

However as a side note, the portion that allows only one instance is indeed working. If I can get constructor with IniliatizeCompotent to work I'll be set. To clarify, any windows that derive from WindowBase can be open at the same time. So in this case, one OptionWindow at a time and one AboutWindow.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="181" Width="259">
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_File"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Tools">
                <MenuItem Header="_Options" ></MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Help">
                <MenuItem Header="_About" Click="AboutMenuItem_Click"></MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="Content would go here"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1 {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AboutMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            AboutWindow.Instance.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

AboutWindow.xaml:

```
<src:WindowBase x:Class="WpfApplication1.AboutWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="AboutWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,74,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</src:WindowBase>
```

AboutWindow.xaml.cs:

```
namespace WpfApplication1 {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for AboutWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class AboutWindow : WindowBase {
        public AboutWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

WindowBase.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1 {
    public partial class WindowBase : Window {
        private static WindowBase instance;

        static WindowBase() {

        }

        private WindowBase() {
            Closed += AbstractWindow_Closed;
        }

        public static WindowBase Instance {
            get {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new WindowBase();
                } return instance;
            }
        }

        private void AbstractWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            instance = null;
        }
    }
}
```

What exactly is the missing piece of the puzzle or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Your problem is that the Instance property in WindowBase is creating a WindowBase object, not an AboutWindow object.

Comment: First, update your question with the following information: Say you have two window types A and B, which both derive from WindowBase. Now, do you want to have either only one A or only one B open, or is it possible to have one window A and one window B open at the same time?

Comment: Updated my question. I was going for the latter, one Window A and one Window B open at the same time. In this case, one OptionWindow and one AboutWindow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Singleton pattern on `MainWindow` is fine, but as @elgonzo said, your `Instance` property in the `AboutWindow` class that you have inherited from the `WindowBase` class returns an instance of `WindowBase`.

Furthermore, any derived class will automatically call the base class constructor when initialised, but your `AboutWindow` constructor is `public` and a `public` constructor cannot call the `private` constructor from the base class.

I have no idea why you're trying to do this instead of simply repeating the Singleton pattern in the `AboutWindow` class. If the case is that you only want to allow one window to be open, regardless of which window that is, then you'll have to use a different method... there is a really simple solution for that requirement and you can find it detailed in the [How can I make sure only one WPF Window is open at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335785/how-can-i-make-sure-only-one-wpf-window-is-open-at-a-time) post here on StackOverflow.

Comment: I do understand that concept of constructors but I'm kind of at a loss as to what I can do about it. As for repeating the Singleton pattern, I absolutely could but I am trying to become a more knowledgeable programmer and am always looking for a better way. And no I don't want to allow only one window to be open, just a window of a certain type. I don't particularly care if someone were to open 6 instances of the actual application, but only one "AboutWindow" or one "OptionWindow". AboutWindow and OptionWindow could be open at the same time however.

Comment: @Rakshasas, repeating the singleton pattern is the way to go. Whatever else you might try, it won't get as readable as `AboutWindow.Instance` or `OtherWindow.Instance`. You could try implementing something like *WindowBase.GetInstance<AboutWindow>()*, but just compare its ugly appearance with the short and succinct *AboutWindow.Instance*. (If you want to have singleton patterns for many types, something like Factory.GetSingletonInstance<T>() might be the way to go, though...)

Comment: Alright. I'll yield to the experts then. I guess it's nice to have a question and basically find out you were on the right track. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need to access the MainWindow while the Window is open, but you can use `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()`.
Then you can't access the underlying window and can't open another one by clicking anything.

Comment: Sorry, but that is a terrible idea and clearly *not* what the question author was asking for. If you edit your answer and improve it, I'd be happy to remove this down vote. However, I'm not really sure how you can improve it starting with what you have.

Comment: I could use ShowDialog() but I absolutely hate it. I find it to generally limit usability of an application. Sometimes there is a purpose for it but I don't want to take away the the ability to use the main window in this case.