# Why does my function to only open one Window not work?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

so I want in my Project to only open 1 instance of my Window. So I gave the Window a Title and tried to track every opening with that:

```
 foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
                {
                    if (window.Title == "QUALI-NET")
                    {
                        temp++;
                    }

                }
```

and then i wanted to call my Function when this if statement is true:

```
 if (temp == 1)
```

I have build this 2 in an extra Class and have an Switch Case around this. Above the Switch Case I initiliaze this:

```
            QualiWindow WPFQuali = new QualiWindow(Mandant, Data.GetValue<string>("Artikelnummer"));
```

But The problem when I Open one Window and then open and another Window then it wont open but when I close the first started Window, I cant open the Window ever Again? I just want to allow one Instance of this Window to open. What am Im doing wrong?

I already tried the solutions from here:
[How can I make sure only one WPF Window is open at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335785/how-can-i-make-sure-only-one-wpf-window-is-open-at-a-time)

But none of that is working. Is there a Way to get every opened Window from taskbar or something and just allow one Window with that name XY. to open

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make sure only one WPF Window is open at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335785/how-can-i-make-sure-only-one-wpf-window-is-open-at-a-time) On another note, look into using a singleton.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://saebamini.com/Allowing-only-one-instance-of-a-C-app-to-run/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're keeping a count of the open windows with that title you also need to decrement the count whenever you close the window.